# Trace of diffusion equation matrix

Tags: calculus, wave-equation, continuum-theory

I'm studying waves moving through mediums and I come across this type of equation a lot while describing acoustic waves speed and stress on the material,

$$\begin{gather}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\begin{bmatrix} A(t,z)  \\ B(t,z)  \end{bmatrix}
 =
 -\frac{1}{c(z)}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   1 &
   0 \\
   0 &
   -1 
   \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} A(t,z)  \\ B(t,z)  \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}$$

and the trace of the matrix on the right hand side, always equals $0.$ Is there a reason for this which is related to energy conservation or something similar? $A$ and $B$ are left and right going waves and $c(z)$ is the wave speed.

I am working on a problem of my own and trying to follow the same theory for elastic waves in mediums, but when I get a similar equation, the matrix on the right hand side does not have a trace of $0$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've made this clearer.

Comment: I will link a paper which is essentially the same equation. See equation 3.9. https://www.math.uci.edu/~ksolna/research/97_1506aniso.pdf

Comment: Is there a reason that the system has this symmetry? I guess what I'm asking is, do you think it's engineered in this way to simplify further calculations?