# vector identities in solving wave equations with different speeds of propagation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-fields, divergence-operator, curl

> Assume that $u = (u^1, u^2, u^3)$ solves the evolution equations of linear elasticity: $$u_{tt}-µ \Delta u − (λ + µ) D (\nabla\cdot u) = 0$$  in $\mathbf{R}^3 × (0, ∞)$.
> Show that $w := \nabla \cdot u $ and $w := \nabla \times u$ each solve wave equations, but with differing speeds of propagation.

This is problem 21 in chapter 2 of Evan's PDE.

I am able to do this problem when $ w := \nabla \times u$ to obtain $w_{tt} = \mu \Delta w$. For $ w:= \nabla \cdot u$, I am not recognizing how to proceed from

$$ w_{tt} = \mu \Delta w + (\lambda + \mu) \nabla (\nabla \cdot w) $$

to $$w_{tt} = \mu (\Delta w) + (\lambda + \mu)(\Delta w)$$

Since $ w = \nabla \cdot u$ is a scalar, I am not sure how the divergence of $w$ is defined here. The identity $\Delta w = \nabla(\nabla \cdot w) - \nabla \times \nabla \times w $ would be useful here but I can't see why the curl of curl of $w$ would be zero in this case or even defined when $w$ is a scalar. Maybe I am misunderstanding something in the statement of the problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm very confused. How can both a scalar and a vector solve the same equation?

Comment: @K.defaoite They don't. They solve wave equations, but one is a vector wave equation and the other is a scalar wave equation.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2395617), which might clear your doubts

Answer (score 1):

Evans means that $\nabla\cdot u$ solves a scalar-valued wave equation and $\nabla\times u$ solves a vector-valued wave equation. Your issue is that you are overloading your derivative operators, in particular $\Delta$. There is a vector Laplacian and a scalar Laplacian in play here. The identity you stated for $\Delta w$ is for a vector Laplacian and only makes sense for a vector-valued function $w$. Since $w = \nabla\cdot u$ is a scalar function, one should use the definition of the scalar Laplacian $\Delta w = \nabla\cdot(\nabla w)$ instead.

Comment: why is $ \nabla \cdot \nabla w = \nabla ( \nabla \cdot w) $? Is the gradient and divergence operator commutative?

Comment: No, that expression makes no sense when $w$ is a scalar function, since $\nabla\cdot w$ is not defined when $w$ is a scalar. The formula $\Delta w = \nabla\cdot(\nabla w)$ involves the gradient of a *scalar* function and the divergence of a *vector* function. The formulas you are trying to apply use the notation $\nabla$ in different ways based on what functions they are applied to, so you can't use the same formulas for vector-valued functions and scalar-valued functions. Forget about the formulas and just work from base definitions if you have to.